# cron will find certain commands on the PATH but not others

Tags: cron

Having issues making crontab run certain commands, despite the PATH and SHELL being set correctly.

Here is the env of the machine:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
USER=ubuntu
MAIL=/var/mail/ubuntu
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/gopath/bin
```

Here is the env of cron (looks the same):

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/gopath/bin
PWD=/home/ubuntu
```

Then, in the crontab:

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/gopath/bin
SHELL=/bin/bash
*/1 * * * * "whoami"
*/1 * * * * "whoami && which whoami"
```

The first `whoami` task succeeds, but the second fails with:

```
/bin/bash: whoami && which whoami: command not found
```

because `which` is not found. However, this is quite strange as:

```
$ which whoami
/usr/bin/whoami

$ which which
/usr/bin/which
```

And `/usr/bin` is on the PATH in cron. What gives?

Comment: Would you try the 2nd command in your sequence by explicitly designating the path of the executable? Also give me the output of: `echo $path` within the context of the `whoami` and `which whoami` commands. Full paths within CronTab commands are a generally accepted best practice. You can also try to set your path as follows: `PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin` It seems like your $PATH has a lot of $CRUD in it, sir.

Comment: */1 * * * * "echo $PATH" gives: "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/gopath/bin" as expected.

Comment: So you are invoking BASH syntax within cron, which won't work. Other poster seconded that. If you are absolutely requiring to do this inside the crontab, instead of an external script, do invoke your commands via bash... So try $> bash -c 'whoami && which whoami'

Comment: Re:CRUD that's (mostly) the default $PATH of EC2 instances.

Comment: So encapsulate your crontab commands inside a bash -c command which exports a bash session... put whatever you need inside '' and you will be able to use operators.

Comment: Thanks -- the env is still not finding /usr/bin/which though, even without operators. (See above.)

Comment: Ok, apologies for my stupidity. I'm using quotes around the commands, which is making cron interpret the whole line as a single command. Closing this issue.

Comment: That is so strange. Then again, Ubuntu is one of my least favorite choices. Apparently, Ubuntu's a bit inherently broken on the CronTab. Please add this to your crontab: env > tmp.dump

Comment: When you have that, post the output of the env command so that we can view your $ENV variables as CronTab interprets them.

Comment: Are you saying that if you remove the quotes it accepts the entry with `&&`? That would be surprising. crontab is not a shell interpreter. I would expect you to have to remove the quotes, and then also follow Unix-Ninja's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't quote the cron job.

You have

```
*/1 * * * * "whoami && which whoami"
```

Which is looking a command literally called `whoami && which whoami`. Such as `/usr/bin/whoami && which whoami`. Obviously, this command does not exist. Remove the quotes so that the command is properly interpreted:

```
*/1 * * * * whoami && which whoami
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, if you want to run multiple commands in a single cron task, you really should put them in a script.

You shouldn't be placing double-quotes around your statement like that. It's likely to be treated as a literal. If you are truly intent on running them inline, you can do something like the following: `bash -c 'whoami && which whoami'`

But again, at that point you should really be placing your commands in a shell script.

Comment: +1 for mentioning `bash -c`.

Comment: */1 * * * * "which whoami" gives "/bin/bash: which whoami: command not found". :-/

Comment: Same for full path: "/bin/bash: /usr/bin/which whoami: No such file or directory"

Comment: That's due to the way the command field is being parsed by cron and passed on. Try it out with the code I put above.

Comment: This is wrong. `man 5 crontab`: `The ``sixth'' field (the rest of the line) specifies the command to be run. The entire command portion of the line, up to a newline or % character, will be executed by /bin/sh or by the shell specified in the SHELL variable of the cronfile.`

Comment: I just realized he was quoting the line, which is wrong. That's probably why it's failing. That being said, && doesn't work for me when I try passing it via cron. It may not execute the second statement for him after he removes the quotes.

Comment: Then your command before the `&&` is failing.

Comment: Your first paragraph is completely wrong. Cron jobs are always interpreted by a shell. Putting `bash -c 'whoami && which whoami'` would have no benefit over plain `whoami && which whoami`.