# Use crontab to invoke nohup in script

Tags: bash, cron, nohup

I'm trying to use crontab to check and re-run a long running script.
I've created a script that checks the status and runs the long-running script if needed.

I'm running the long running script with nohup to keep it running when I log out.

The keep-alive script:

```
#!/bin/bash

BASE_PATH=~/scripts
LOG_PATH=${BASE_PATH}/keep_alive.log

write_to_log () {
    date >> ${LOG_PATH}
    echo ${1} >> ${LOG_PATH}
    echo "--------------" >> ${LOG_PATH}
}

pid=$(pgrep long_script)
 if [ -z "${pid}" ]; then
    write_to_log "long_script is no runnig, starting..."
    nohup ${BASE_PATH}/long_script.py &
fi
```

crontab entry:

```
*/30 * * * * /home/user/scripts/keep_alive.sh
```

When I run the script manually (in bash, ./keep-alive.sh) all works well and the long script starts.

From crontab, the script starts and exits immediately (no issue with the paths/expression), and I see a log written, but the long script stops. So my conclusion is that nohup doesn't work the same for crontab as in bash.

I tired using setsid or disown, but got the same results.

How can I solve it?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you try seeing the path for `nohup` from `which nohup` and use the path directly in crontab? It is possible that cron might not know `PATH` thereby not know where to find nohup

Comment: Related - [BashScript works from Terminal but not from CronTab](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/185236/100397)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for `nohup` when using `crontab`. Unless your `systemd` is configured to kill all your processes when you log out there is no interaction between your shell exiting and `crontab` running processes (or otherwise), and `nohup` will have no useful effect on that.

Look at your local email (`mail` or `mailx`) and read the error messages reported there from `cron` - or `less /var/mail/$USER` if you want a shortcut. Alternatively change your `crontab` line to capture *stdout* and *stderr* to a file you can review later

```
*/30 * * * * /home/user/scripts/keep_alive.sh >ka.log 2>&1
```

Typically scripts don't run under `cron` because you've forgotten to set up the environment (`$PATH`, etc.).

Comment: Redirecting stdout did the trick :) The issue indeed was environment (the script couldn't find a file), nothing to do with the nohup.